# How to increase the layout of text box in angular-2 material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-material

In angular material 1 we are having layout property called **flex-gt-xs**.what is the **equivalent to this in angular-2 material** and if any one knows any usable **links for layout in angular-2 material**

example

```
 <md-input placeholder="check" flex-gt-xs ></md-input>
```

The above markups didn't throw any error but the layout is also not working in angular-2 material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at their documentation it seems like this feature doesn't implemented yet: [Angular material 2 documentation](https://github.com/angular/material2)
Look at that big table, and search for "layout" in the first column. It says: Not started.

You can use CSS3 flexbox to achieve the same result (with a little bit of extra work). Also you may want to use media queries to create a responsive layout.

If you don't want to bother with media queries, check out this project: [Flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/). It gives you a framework to deal with responsive layouts, it's similar to bootstrap's layout system, fairly easy to use.
I've used it before, pretty good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes @jester_racer i read out the github documentation of angular material2.I raised this question to find any other way for this.